# Why is linked in giving me a security code instead of redirecting back to my application with a token?

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn PHP Oauth example found here:

https://github.com/petewarden/linkedinoauthexample

I've found it much easier to understand and use compared to other options so I'd like to stick with it. The author has an example based on the same code that I am using, which works exactly how I want my application to work. The only problem is that instead of redirecting back to my application after authorization, it gives me a security code...

> You have successfully authorized *My Application*
>
> Please return to your application and enter the following security code to grant access:

I've only slightly modified the author's example to be used as a CodeIgniter library. [Here](http://pastie.org/1976414) is the modified example code. And [here](http://pastie.org/1976421) is how I am calling it within CodeIgniter.

Why is it not redirecting to my application with the token instead?

Comment: You can find email of author of code (Pete Warden) in README.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added Pastie links to the code.

Comment: Well something is wrong with the way this library is sending the callback... but there is a option in the Application Settings for the API key where you can override the callback, which works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, that means you're not setting the callback URL properly. (Or not setting a callback at all, so it's defaulting to the OOB setting.)

It would take me time to read all that code and figure out the exact issue, but there does appear to be lots of error_log()ging. So, I would check to see what's setting set where. I would also try and look at the raw HTTP messages... that would help me identify what's missing where, and then we could look at that spot in the code.

Comment: I was able to override the callback by setting an option on my LinkedIn API key settings (in my developer account) but determined that the library is incorrectly sending the callback url to the wrong steps of the authentication process.. http://www.slideshare.net/episod/linkedin-oauth-zero-to-hero was a good resource